# YouTube api returns 404 liveBroadcastNotFound for existing liveBroadcast on status transition from "live" to "complete"

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using **Node.js** as a backend technology and [googleapis library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) as a tool for simple YouTube-api integration.

```
const {
    google: {
        auth: { OAuth2 },
        youtube,
    },
} = GoogleApis;

const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(tokenId, secretKey, redirectUrl);
const youTube = youtube({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client });
```

Flow:

**1)** liveBroadcast creation.

```
youTube.liveBroadcasts.insert({
    part: 'id,snippet,status,contentDetails',
    requestBody: {
        snippet,
        contentDetails: { monitorStream: { enableMonitorStream: false } },
        status: { privacyStatus: 'public' },
    },
}),
```

snippet contains scheduledStartTime, title and description.

**2)** liveStream creation.

```
youTube.liveStreams.insert({
    part: 'id,snippet,cdn',
    requestBody: {
        snippet,
        cdn: {
            ingestionType: 'rtmp',
            frameRate: 'variable',
            resolution: 'variable',
        },
    },
}),
```

snippet contains title and description.

**3)** bind liveBroadcast to liveStream

```
youTube.liveBroadcasts.bind({
    part: 'id',
    id,
    streamId,
}),
```

At this point liveBroadcast status is "ready", liveStream status - "ready".

**4)** start broadcasting video stream to YouTube using liveStream rtmp key.

**5)** wait 15 seconds.

At this point liveBroadcast status is "ready", liveStream status - "active".

**6)** make liveBroadcast status transition from "ready" to "live"

```
youTube.liveBroadcasts.transition({
    part: 'id',
    id,
    broadcastStatus: 'live',
}),
```

At this point liveBroadcast status is "live", liveStream status - "active".

Up until now everything works fine, as expected.

**7)** make liveBroadcast status transition from "live" to "complete".

```
youTube.liveBroadcasts.transition({
    part: 'id',
    id,
    broadcastStatus: 'complete',
}),
```

And here happens dark magic: `YouTube-api` returns `404 liveBroadcastNotFound`.

liveBroadcast seems to disappear.
This liveBroadcast appears(becomes available) after several hours-days.

As a response I get next error response(paste JSON below in [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.org)):

> {"response":{"config":{"url":"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?part=id&id=${liveBroadcastIdReplacedHere}&broadcastStatus=complete","method":"POST","headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip","User-Agent":"google-api-nodejs-client/2.0.4
>   (gzip)","Authorization":"Bearer
>   ${jwtTokenReplacedHere}","Accept":"application/json"},"params":{"part":"id","id":"${liveBroadcastIdReplacedHere}","broadcastStatus":"complete"},"retry":true,"responseType":"json","retryConfig":{"currentRetryAttempt":0,"retry":3,"retryDelay":100,"httpMethodsToRetry":["GET","HEAD","PUT","OPTIONS","DELETE"],"noResponseRetries":2,"statusCodesToRetry":[[100,199],[429,429],[500,599]]}},"data":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"youtube.liveBroadcast","reason":"liveBroadcastNotFound","message":"Broadcast
>   not found"}],"code":404,"message":"Broadcast not
>   found"}},"headers":{"alt-svc":"quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000;
>   v=\"46,43\",h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\";
>   ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000","cache-control":"private,
>   max-age=0","connection":"close","content-encoding":"gzip","content-type":"application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8","date":"Wed, 02 Oct 2019 13:10:02 GMT","expires":"Wed,
>   02 Oct 2019 13:10:02
>   GMT","server":"GSE","transfer-encoding":"chunked","vary":"Origin,
>   X-Origin","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-xss-protection":"1;
>   mode=block"},"status":404,"statusText":"Not
>   Found"},"config":{"url":"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?part=id&id=${liveBroadcastIdReplacedHere}&broadcastStatus=complete","method":"POST","headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip","User-Agent":"google-api-nodejs-client/2.0.4
>   (gzip)","Authorization":"Bearer
>   ${jwtTokenReplacedHere}","Accept":"application/json"},"params":{"part":"id","id":"${liveBroadcastIdReplacedHere}","broadcastStatus":"complete"},"retry":true,"responseType":"json","retryConfig":{"currentRetryAttempt":0,"retry":3,"retryDelay":100,"httpMethodsToRetry":["GET","HEAD","PUT","OPTIONS","DELETE"],"noResponseRetries":2,"statusCodesToRetry":[[100,199],[429,429],[500,599]]}},"code":404,"errors":[{"domain":"youtube.liveBroadcast","reason":"liveBroadcastNotFound","message":"Broadcast
>   not found"}]}

I get the same error using [YouTube UI for developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition)

[status transition screenshots](https://dropmefiles.com.ua/HKTwkQ54)

Comment: are you ending your rtmp before you call  transition from "live" to "complete" ? It could be that the rtmp is ending the broadcast before you actually do the call